# How can I use the same parameters in a decorator with that in the functions in Python?

Tags: python

I want use a same param in decorater and function like:

```py
def outer(deco_param):
    def decorator(func):
        print("param:%s" % deco_param)
        return func
    return decorator


@outer(deco_param=s)    # problems here: 's' is unreferenced
def test(s):
    print("test:%s" % s)
```

I got this idea when using `Flask` but I didn't know how did they make it, which supports using a param of view function in its decorater like:

```
app.route(rule="/user/<int:uid>")
def access_user(uid):  # if I use any other name except from 'uid', IDE would raise a tip
    ...
```

What's more, `Flask` seems to make **a static check**. If I miss `uid` argument or use any other name, IDE(pycharm) would raise a tip of "Function 'access_user` doesn't have a parameter 'int:uid'". **That's the effect I want.**

Can anyone please give me some advice? Thanks

Comment: "problems here: 's' is unreferenced" right, that problem has nothing to do with the decorator, you simply haven't defined the variable `s`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga trank you! You gave me some idea on how Flask makes it: by **using a string instead of a variable**. But my question is that Flask makes it not in running time, **but in "compile time" instead**(I don't know if it's proper to say a complie time in python). If I missed param in function decorated, my IDE(pycharm) would give me a tip of "Function 'access_user' doesn't have a parameter 'int:uid'

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the same parameter to both the outer function and the inner function. To call the parameters via decorator, you should add a wrapper function to pass the parameters (*args) from inner one to outer one.

You can write like this:

```
def outer():
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args):
            print("param:%s" % func.__param__)
            return func(*args)
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@outer
def test(s):
    print("test:%s" % s)
```

Comment: Thanks. But the problem here is that I don't want to hard code the connection between params as not every function decorated has a param s. I just want something like that in Flask which supports designating a param of function to decorater function.